# Java: InternetAddress

Tags: java

I am storing my emails in database by using 
`InternetAddress.toUnicodeString()`.

It gives me such string: `"John Doe" <doe@john.com>`

The question: how can I parse that string in order to convert it back to `InternetAddress`?

Thank you

Comment: You can create object by using: new InternetAddress(email_id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ummm... perhaps by using the [constructor that takes a String parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress%28java.lang.String%29)? Please learn to use the Javadoc API - you'll find answers much faster than by asking here.

Comment: Is this a question-and-answer site? Perhaps we should drop stackoverflow all together, on the premise that everything (more or less) is in the docs and we have google on top of that. Even if nKognito had to wait for your helpful answer, 502 persons (and counting) after him did not.

Answer (score 3):

According to the javadoc, the InternetAddress.toUnicodeString() method is *supposed to* give you an RFC 822 compliant email address decoded as unicode characters.  But "John Doe" is not an RFC 822 compliant email address at all.  This points to the problem being with whatever is creating those InternetAddress objects in the first place.

Certainly, there is no way to "parse" the string "John Doe" and extract a valid email address.  The information is simply not there to be extracted.  Perhaps you could do a lookup in a local address book database.

---

**UPDATE** -

The way to turn `"John Doe" <doe@john.com>` into an InternetAddress is to use the `InternetAddress(String)` constructor ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress%28java.lang.String%29)).  That will parse the input String automatically.

Comment: I am sorry, didn't noticed that the email was trimmed

Answer (score 0):

I would say, impossible. <del>You should rather choose between storing a email address the full length in your database, or by storing an id of the email address (which requires a separate table for email addresses).</del>

Just make sure that your InternetAddress object is valid. Try to call validate() on it to see if it is actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can use new InternetAddress(emailAddress,personalName) method in your case.